# Unexpected tokens, syntax error on if statement,

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, scripting

I am having a problem with my if statement, for some reason it will not run. here is the code:

```
if (( $digit1 -ne $digit2 )); then
 echo "test"

fi
```

I get this error message:  `line 32: ((: 1 -ne 2 : syntax error in expression (error token is "2 ")`

** I have digit set to 2

Answer (score 1):

You are using the form:

```
((expression))
```

which evaluates the expression according to the rules of Arithmetic Evalution.

You have two options.  Either fix the operator, i.e. use `!=`:

```
if (( d1 != d2 )); then
```

or use `test`:

```
if [ $d1 -ne $d2 ]; then
```

If you're using the arithmetic context:

```
    !, ~        logical and bitwise negation
```

Quoting from `help test`:

```
  arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                 -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
```

Answer (score 1):

As @devnull said and adding to that, use :

```
 if [ $digi1 -ne $digi2 ]; then
   echo "Unequal numbers"
 fi
```